# Given a webpage url, how can I fetch it's content data to generate link preview like in Facebook and Slack?

Tags: ios

For example, in Slack, when I paste the following url 
http://time.com/4023256/hillary-clinton-donald-trump-unfortunate-development/?xid=homepage

slack's shows a preview of it's content
[image]

How can I implement such function in my iOS app?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ReadabilityKit, it gives you an ability to extract a relevant metadata (for example, title, description and top image) from the URL.
https://github.com/exyte/ReadabilityKit

```
let parser = Readability(url: articleUrl)

let title = parser.title()
let description = parser.description()
let keywords = parser.keywords()
let imageUrl = parser.imageUrl()
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an opensource web service for that with naive api: http://proc.link

Or you can build your own with this: https://github.com/dyatlov/proclink-api

Answer (score 1):

Facebook uses special meta tags in the page's header to grab title, summary, thumbnail etc. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters if it doesn't find those tags it will use standard HTML tags `<h1>...<h6>` or page's title and images to generate preview...
Anyways, I think you shouldn't implement this in iOS, instead you'll need a service (server side scripts) which grabs the URL, parses the page and passes back the preview components to the iOS app, because this is much easier to achieve with Node.js PHP Python etc. than with Swift or Objective-C